# use setAttribute and createElement | PHP XML

Tags: php, xml

This code:

```
$product = $dom->createElement('o');
     
     $product->setAttribute('id', $productSku);
     
     $product->setAttribute('url', $productWebsite.$productUrl);
     
     $product->setAttribute('price', substr_replace($productPrice,'.',-2,0).$productCurrency); 
     
     $product->setAttribute('avail', $productAvail);
     
     $product->setAttribute('weight', $productWeight);
     
     $product->setAttribute('stock', $productStock);
     
     $product->setAttribute('basket', $productBasket);
```

Generate for me:

```
<offers><o id="12264" url="http" price="209.22" avail="1" weight="1" stock="183" basket="1">
```

Now I add:

```
//tag
     $title = $dom->createElement('name', clean($productTitle)); 

     $product->appendChild($title);
```

and under this xml line I have

```
<name>some name</name>
```

everything is okay! But I need   add  next tags under this all lines to get result:

```
<imgs>
      <main url="https://firstimage1"/>
</imgs>
```

so now  I try:

```
 $product = $dom->createElement('imgs');
$product->setAttribute('main', $productImagePath.$productImage);
```

What is issue?

- This code replace first  tag `o` with `imgs` and tag `main` add to first tag with <o some like this by end of line:

  ```
  <offers><imgs id="12264" url="http" price="209.22" avail="1" weight="1" stock="183" basket="1" main="https:urlphoto">
  ```

This is wrong. I need to get full effect:

```
<offers><o id="12264" url="http" price="209.22" avail="1" weight="1" stock="183" basket="1">
<name>some name</name>
<imgs>
          <main url="https://firstimage1"/>
    </imgs>
</o>
</offers>
```

full code:

```
      $product = $dom->createElement('o');
         
         $product->setAttribute('id', $productSku);
         
         $product->setAttribute('url', $productWebsite.$productUrl);
         
         $product->setAttribute('price', substr_replace($productPrice,'.',-2,0).$productCurrency); 
         
         $product->setAttribute('avail', $productAvail);
         
         $product->setAttribute('weight', $productWeight);
         
         $product->setAttribute('stock', $productStock);
         
         $product->setAttribute('basket', $productBasket);
        
    
         //tag
         $title = $dom->createElement('name', clean($productTitle)); 
    
         $product->appendChild($title);
         
         // next element (issue here) this replace first tags
         
         $product = $dom->createElement('imgs');
         
         $product->setAttribute('main', $productImagePath.$productImage);



$root->appendChild($product);
     
     

   }

   $dom->appendChild($root); 

   $dom->save($filePath); 

 }
```

@update:
I try change:

```
// next element
     
         // next element
 
 $product2 = $dom->createElement('imgs');
 
 $product3 = $dom->createElement('main');
 
 $product3->setAttribute('url', $productImagePath.$productImage);
```

and by end of file:

```
 $root->appendChild($product);
 $root->appendChild($product2);
 $root->appendChild($product3);
```

But now I have:

```
<offers>
<o id="12264" url="http" price="209.22" avail="1" weight="1" stock="183" basket="1">
<name>4711 Eau De Cologne 800ml</name>
</o>
<imgs/>
```

@update 2:
@Thank you for answear. This working correct! Can I ask you about last thing.

I need add again:

```
<attrs>
      <a name="Producent">
        <![CDATA[Avery]]>
      </a>
      <a name="EAN">
        <![CDATA[9084692100225]]>
      </a>
      <a name="Kod producenta">
        <![CDATA[AVSG710022]]>
      </a>
    </attrs>
```

For this I duplicate function:

```
  // create+append "attrs" to "o"
    $offer->appendChild(
      $attrs = $document->createElement('attrs')
    );
    // create+append "a" to "attrs"
    $attrs->appendChild(
      $attr = $document->createElement('a')
    );
    // add properties to the "attrs" element
    $attr->setAttribute('producent', $productBrand);
    $attr->setAttribute('ean', $productEan);
    $attr->setAttribute('kod_producent', $productSku);
```

But currently I've:

```
   <attrs>
      <a producent="4711" ean="4011700740031" kod_producent="12264"/>
    </attrs>
```

Comment: `$product = $dom->createElement('imgs');` overwrites the `$product` variable you previously created. If you want to keep both, store them in different variables.

Comment: `$product->setAttribute('main'...` sets an attribute in your current element. But i thing you wan to create an new element here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You named the `imgs` element node variable `$product` and overwrite the `o` element - its parent node. Make sure to use semantic and unique names for your variables.

Use methods on the DOM document to create the nodes and append them to their parent node. `appendChild()` returns the appended node, so you can use it to chain calls and only need to store the node into a variable for extended modification.

Do not use the second argument of `createElement()`. It does not fully escape special characters. Set the `textContent` property or append a text node.

You can append the element node directly after creating it - here is no need to wait. You can modify the appended node at any time - this are the same methods you use to manipulate existing nodes.

Here is an example that creates your target XML structure (with reduced attributes).

```php
$document = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

// create+append the document element "offers"
$document->appendChild(
  $offers = $document->createElement('offers')
);

// create+append the "o" element
$offers->appendChild(
  $offer = $document->createElement('o')
);
// add properties to the "o" element
$offer->setAttribute('id', 'SKU123');
$offer->setAttribute('url', 'https://example.com#product');

// create+append the "name" to "o"
$offer
  ->appendChild($document->createElement('name'))
  // chain call and set the text content
  ->textContent = 'Example product name';

// create+append "imgs" to "o"
$offer->appendChild(
  $images = $document->createElement('imgs')
);
// create+append "main" to "imgs"
$images->appendChild(
  $image = $document->createElement('main')
);
// add properties to the "main" element
$image->setAttribute('url', 'https://example.com#product-image');

$document->formatOutput = true;
echo $document->saveXML();
```

Output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<offers>
  <o id="SKU123" url="https://example.com#product">
    <name>Example product name</name>
    <imgs>
      <main url="https://example.com#product-image"/>
    </imgs>
  </o>
</offers>
```

Comment: I noticed one issue with this . $document->formatOutput = true;
echo $document->saveXML(); In database I've above 50k+ products. And with this when I generate products, then I have in file only about 5k products.

Comment: and I checked by end of file and is some like this  example <desc>Lolita Lempicka Mon Premier Eau De Perfume Spray 100ml</desc>
    <attrs>
      <a producent="LOLITA LEMPICKA"/>
      <a ean="3760269849303"/>
      <a kod_producenta="241252"/>
    </attrs>  so you see in this case missing </o> and </offers>  and that's because it's as if the feed generation was interrupted at some point. Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: For large exports DOM is not the right XML API because it keeps the whole structure in memory, check out [XMLWriter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/example.xmlwriter-oop.php). Also if the task takes to long you might need to move it to the console and into a cronjob.

Comment: this is very strange, because script take about max 2-3 second and no display timeout etc. But  can you please check this screen https://prnt.sc/ukvBHWUPLn7r generate only about 4.5k products and you see is not complete xml. Example here  by end of file is start products in <o and only to <imgs> wihout finish. In database is about 50k products

Comment: and for this our old script code we correct generate to xml ALL products from database. and when we replace some code to your generate only  this  about 4k. Do you know why this happen?